# Android-Change scroll animation as acceleration deceleration

Tags: android, listview, animation, scroll, acceleration

I have listView implemented. When I scroll programmatically, it scrolling animation is very fast. I want the scroll animation to accelerate and then decelerate with a Maximum velocity (and/or duration) provided by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://github.com/daimajia/AnimationEasingFunctions

For example:

```
    AnimatorSet animation = new AnimatorSet();
    animation.playTogether(Glider.glide(Skill.CubicEaseInOut, 500f, ObjectAnimator.ofInt(listView, "scrollY", itemView.getTop())));
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.start();
```

where `Skill.CubicEaseInOut` is type of animation acording http://easings.net/

I hope this helps